# How to get a confirmation box when value change in h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu, confirm

I'm having trouble trying to get a confirmation box when someone change the value in a h:selectOneMenu and if the person accept, then the value changes, otherwise it return to its original value.

I do not know how to manage to do this, I have made some research but most of the answer I found were for PrimeFaces (which I do not use).

Here's the relevant part of code with the selectOneMenu :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{CommandeBean.choixMetaProprietes}" var="choixMetaProprietes">
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{choixMetaProprietes.metaProprieteSelectionnee}">
        <f:selectItems noSelectionValue="#{CommandeBean.retrieveDefaultMetaProprietesValue()}" value="#{choixMetaProprietes.metaProprietes}" var="metaPropriete" itemLabel="#{metaProprieteConverter.getMetaProprieteLabel(metaPropriete)}" itemValue="#{metaPropriete}"/>
        <f:converter converterId="com.festo.didactic.ca.webapp.entreecommandes.converter.MetaProprieteConverter"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat>
```

I'm open to any idea that could help me solve this problem.

Comment: What is that confirmation box here?

Comment: Maybe he means the javascript confirmation dialog.

Comment: Hi, i would like to ask the user something like "Do you really wish to change ..." and if the answer is yes, then the value is changed, otherwise it return to its original value.

Comment: @BalusC is there a simple way to trigger this when the value has changed  and revert the modification if the answer is no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally manage to do it by storing the data in an input hidden and then compare the actual value of the selectOneMenu with the input in query.

i was then able to call a confirmation box via `confirm('blabla bla')`.
the result would then tell me if i need to keep the value or put the previous one.